# RTL Preview on Android Studio XML

Tags: xml, android-studio, preview, right-to-left

> Is it possible to preview the RTL view for layouts in XML Preview on Android Studio?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For preview you can set your xml parent view with `android:layoutDirection="rtl"`

For example,

item.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="2dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
>
//design
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**android:layoutDirection="rtl"**

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: For preview only you can use tools package. (tools:layoutDirection="rtl")

Comment: you should use tools package instead because `android:` will change the layout direction not only in preview but also in the app.

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution to preview RTL would be to Force RTL from Developers Options.